# Statistics of the product of two white noise Fourier amplitudes

Tags: statistics, fourier-analysis, noise

Consider two sequences of random numbers

\begin{align}
A &= \{a_0, a_1, \ldots a_N\} \\
B &= \{b_0, b_1, \ldots b_N\} \, .
\end{align}

where each $a$ and $b$ value is independently drawn from a Gaussian distribution

$$G_\sigma(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}} \exp \left[ -\frac{x^2}{2 \sigma^2}\right] \, .$$

Suppose we compute the discrete Fourier transform of each sequence

\begin{align}
\tilde{A}_k &\equiv \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} a_n \exp\left[-i 2 \pi n k / N \right] \\
\tilde{B}_k &\equiv \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} b_n \exp\left[-i 2 \pi n k / N \right] \, .
\end{align}

What is the statistical distribution of

$$\tilde{C}_k \equiv \tilde{A}_k \tilde{B}_k^* \, ?$$

---

### Attempt

Using the fact that the distribution of a sum of random variables is the convolution of the distributions of the things being summed, we can find that $\tilde{A}_k$ is a complex number whose real and imaginary parts are independent and both Gaussian distributed with standard deviation $\sigma \sqrt{2N}$.
Then, using the rules for transformation of random variables (and the convolution rule again) we can find that the distribution of the square of the radius

$$r^2 \equiv (\text{Re} \tilde{A}_k)^2 + (\text{Im} \tilde{A}_k)^2$$

is

$$P_{r^2}(\alpha) = \frac{1}{\sigma^2 N} \exp \left[ -\alpha/\sigma^2 N \right] \qquad (\alpha > 0) \, .$$

Again using transformation rules we find the distribution of the radius

$$P_r(r) = \left( \frac{2}{\sigma^2 N} \right) r \exp\left[-r^2 / \sigma^2 N \right] \qquad (r > 0) \, .$$

Note that from this we can compute $\langle r \rangle = \sigma \sqrt{\pi N} / 2$.

The statistics of $\tilde{B}_k$ are obviously the same as the statistics of $\tilde{A}_k$.

Now we consider $\tilde{C}_k \equiv \tilde{A}_k \tilde{B}_k$.
The phase of $\tilde{C}_k$ is the sum of the phases of $\tilde{A}_k$ and $\tilde{B}_k$.
As the phases of $\tilde{A}_k$ and $\tilde{B}_k$ are both uniformly distributed over $[0,\pi)$, it's obvious that the phase of $\tilde{C}_k$ is also uniformly distributed over that range.
The radius is the interesting part.
The radius of the product is the product of the radii.
Fortunately, we know that the [product of two random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution) $Z=XY$ follows the distribution

$$P_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty P_X(x) P_Y(z/x) \frac{1}{|x|}dx \, .$$

Therefore, the distribution of the radius of $\tilde{C}_k$ is

\begin{align}
P_{|\tilde{C}_k|}(z)
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty P_r(r) P_r(z/r) \frac{dr}{|r|} \\
&= \int_0^\infty P_r(r) P_r(z/r) \frac{dr}{r} \\
&= \left( \frac{2}{\sigma^2 N} \right)^2 z \int_0^\infty \exp \left[ - \frac{ r^2 + (z/r)^2 }{\sigma^2 N} \right] \frac{dr}{r} \, .
\end{align}

I have not been able to solve this integral.
However, we can find the average value of $|\tilde{C}_k|$:
\begin{align}
\langle |\tilde{C}_k| \rangle
&= \int_0^\infty z P_{|\tilde{C}_k|}(z) \, dz \\
&= \left( \frac{2}{\sigma^2 N}\right)^2 \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty dz \, dr \, \frac{z^2}{r} \exp \left(-\left(r^2 + (z/r)^2 \right)/(\sigma^2 N) \right) \\
&= \left( \frac{2}{\sigma^2 N}\right)^2 \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4} (\sigma^2 N)^{3/2}
\int_0^\infty dr \, r^2 \exp \left( -r^2 / \sigma^2 N \right) \\
&= \frac{\pi}{4} \sigma^2 N \, .
\end{align}
which, interestingly, is exactly the square of $\langle r \rangle$ for either $\tilde{A}_k$ or $\tilde{B}_k$.
This is better than nothing, but the full distribution remains to be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a very *fun* answer, but your integral can be solved explicitly by using e.g. Mathematica. Given the following input:

> Integrate[Exp[(-r^2 - (z/r)^2)/([Sigma]^2 n)]/r, {r, 0, [Infinity]},
>     Assumptions -> [Sigma] > 0 && n > 0 && z > 0]

The computer spits out the explicit solution: Simply a Bessel function. The final result is

$$ P(z)=\bigg(\frac{2}{\sigma^2N}\bigg)^2 z \cdot \underbrace{K_0\bigg(\frac{2z}{N\sigma^2}\bigg)}_{\text{integral}}$$

Where $K_0$ is defined [e.g. on this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html). One particularly simple representation for it is

$$K_0(z)=\int_0^\infty \cos(z\sinh t)\mathrm d t $$

Perhaps, one can actually construct this solution by hand once the answer is known, but I'll leave that as a proverbial *exercise to the reader*.

Comment: It would be nice to link to the definition of $K_0$, since there are at least one bajillion different things called "Bessel function".

Comment: @DanielSank Of course, sorry. I linked to the corresponding page in the online Mathematica "guide"